# Enviar y recibir variable desde login de Laravel

Tags: laravel, formularios, login

Tengo una vista con un formulario que solo tiene un select con unos períodos escolares. Desde esa vista quiero enviar el período hacia la vista del login para guardarlo en un input oculto y luego desde el login enviar el período hacia la vista home en donde solo hay una tabla en donde quiero que se muestren los registros correspondientes al período que se seleccionó inicialmente.

Esa era la idea inicial. Cómo no pude enviar desde la vista con el select al formulario, lo que hice fue editar el formulario que viene por defecto con laravel para agregarle el select y ahorrarme el primer paso.

[image: Imagen del login de laravel modificado]

Ahora lo que me hace falta es pasar esa variable periodo hacia la vista que sale después de autenticarme. Agredezco su ayuda.

Comment: Ese valor afecta al usuario que quiere iniciar sesión?

Comment: Para iniciar sesión es el mismo proceso de siempre en el que se consulta el correo y la contraseña en la tabla users. Lo que quiero es que haga la validación de esos dos campos y que además pase una variable a la siguiente vista.